# MySQL Convert a SUM of 0 rows to an integer 0

Tags: mysql

On my MySQL trip, MySQL challenges me more and more. Let's say I have TableA and TableB with following structure (it is simplified to point out the problem):

```
TableA
+------------------+
| IDA| Description |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Something   |
| 2  | Else        |
| 3  | IDK         |
+------------------+

TableB
+------------------+
| IDA   | Amount   |
|------------------|
| 1     | 5        |
| 2     | 7        |
| 2     | 17       |
| 1     | 15       |
+------------------+
```

My goal is now, that I sum up the amount for every id. Therefore I use following code

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TableB WHERE IDA = a.IDA) as Total, Description FROM TableA a
```

This code works as long I have a row in my `TableB`. In this example, **I get for IDA 3 a Total of `NULL`**. In my more complex code, I am going to calculate with this code so the whole field returns `NULL`.

- **Am I able to replace the `NULL` with 0 or convert it?**
- **Is it possible to make if else clause there?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(IFNULL(amount,0)) FROM TableB WHERE IDA = a.IDA) as Total, Description FROM TableA a
```

The part `IFNULL(amount,0)` means *when amount is not null return amount else return 0*.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `coalesce` and `left join`

```
select a.*,
coalesce(sum(b.Amount),0) 
from tablea a
left join tableb b using(IDA)
group by a.IDA
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/572bf4/1)